# VB.NET to C# conversion -- Interface Event declaration for non-EventHandler events

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Ran into this while converting a VB.NET interface to C#; the VB version defines an event which doesn't conform to the typical (object sender, EventArgs e) signature:

VB

```
Public Class SomeType
    ' Does *NOT* inherit from EventArgs
End Class

Public Interface ISomething
    Public Event SomeEvent(sender as Object, value as SomeType)
End Interface
```

What's the C# equivalent for ISomething?  My attempts so far have failed to compile:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need a delegate type declaration:

```
public delegate void SomeEventHandler(object sender, SomeType value)

public class SomeType
{
}

public interface ISomething
{
    public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;
}
```

Or in .NET 3.5 you *could* use the built-in Action type:

```
public class SomeType
{
}

public interface ISomething
{
    public event Action<object, SomeType> SomeEvent;
}
```

Comment: That's close to what I tried; to keep the delegate's name the same I tried declaring it within the C# interface--but it failed to compile.  Is it possible to declare a delegate as part of an interface, or will the delegate have to reside outside of the interface?

Comment: It'll have to be outside the interface - unlike VB, C# doesn't allow nested types within an interface (which is a pain for a few things, but never mind).